# Weird error when trying to debug golang on VSCode debugger in Test mode

Tags: go, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am hitting the `Debug` button in `VSCode`

with the following configuration

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Debug",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "env": {
                    "VAR1": "admin",
                    "VAR2": "supersecretpassword",
                    "VAR3": "doesnotmatter_1",
                    "VAR3": "doesnotmatter_2",
                },
        },
            {
                "name": "Test",
                "type": "go",
                "request": "launch",
                "mode": "test",
                "program": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "env": {
                    "VAR1": "admin",
                    "VAR2": "supersecretpassword",
                    "VAR3": "doesnotmatter_1",
                    "VAR4": "doesnotmatter_2",
                },
            }
    ]
}
```

(I am selecting the `Test` mode

and for the first time in my life I get the following error:

> Failed to launch: could not launch process: open
> /Users/pantelis/Workspace/eck-user-mgmt/__debug_bin: no
> such file or directory

I am pretty sure I run this process at most a couple of days ago.

Any ideas?

(when selecting the `Debug` mode the process seems to be working as expected)

**edit 1**: I changed the `Test` configuration to the following

```
                "name": "Test",
                "type": "go",
                "request": "launch",
                "mode": "test",
                "program": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "env": {
                    "VAR1": "admin",
                    "VAR2": "supersecretpassword",
                    "VAR3": "doesnotmatter_1",
                    "VAR4": "doesnotmatter_2",
                    "trace": "verbose",
                    "showLog": true,
                    "logOutput": "dap",
                },
            }
```

It still fails but no particular error (or extra info in the `DEBUG CONSOLE` output view

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you collect logs and share it (NOTE: delete sensitive info in the trace before sharing)? https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/debugging.md#collecting-logs

Comment: Not sure if I followed the debug instructions correctly; check my update on the question